# If same first few digits of ID, how to keep rows based on multiple conditions?

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I have a df containing the fertility history of each woman. There are 18 rows for each woman (i.e. id_mdob) because I'm reconstructing her births from the past 18 years.

My problem is that there are a few cases where the same woman shows up more than "once" (i.e. more than 18 times). For example, id_mdob 321988 shows up 36 times. Same for 321991. This is because the data is from 2 different waves, or years, but I only need data from 1 year. I determine which year I want to keep with the following critera (essentially, I keep either the year where the woman has kids or if none, then the more recent year):

1. If the first 6 digits of id_mdob_sy are the same, keep:

a.) The id_mdob_sy that has at least 1 non-missing value in the
nchild1-nchild10 columns.

2. If columns nchild1-nchild10 are all NA (i.e. the woman has no kids),
   then keep:

b.) the id_mdob_sy with the higher number.

So for example:

- 3219882014 and 3219882015 --> keep 3219882015 bc neither of the 2
  have at least 1 non-missing value in the nchild1-nchild10 columns AND
  year 2015 > year 2014
- 3219912016 and 3219912017 --> keep 3219912017 bc there's at least 1 non-missing value in the nchild1-nchild10 columns (nchild1=2015).

So far, I've come up with the following code, but idk how to specify the last part (to keep the id_mdob_sy with the higher number/more recent year):

```
test <- df %>%
  group_by(id_mdob_sy) %>%
  filter(as.numeric(substr(id_mdob_sy, 6)) & ifelse(!is.na %in% c(nchild1, nchild2, nchild3, nchild4, nchild5, nchild6, nchild7, nchild8, nchild9, nchild10)))
  
test2 <- test
  group_by(id_mdob_sy) %>%
  filter(as.numeric(substr(id_mdob_sy, 6)) & ifelse(is.na %in% c(nchild1, nchild2, nchild3, nchild4, nchild5, nchild6, nchild7, nchild8, nchild9, nchild10)))
```

Here are the first 115 rows of the df:

```
structure(list(id_mdob_sy = c(1119902018, 1119902018, 1119902018, 
1119902018, 1119902018, 1119902018, 1119902018, 1119902018, 1119902018, 
1119902018, 1119902018, 1119902018, 1119902018, 1119902018, 1119902018, 
1119902018, 1119902018, 1119902018, 2219952018, 2219952018, 2219952018, 
2219952018, 2219952018, 2219952018, 2219952018, 2219952018, 2219952018, 
2219952018, 2219952018, 2219952018, 2219952018, 2219952018, 2219952018, 
2219952018, 2219952018, 2219952018, 3119802018, 3119802018, 3119802018, 
3119802018, 3119802018, 3119802018, 3119802018, 3119802018, 3119802018, 
3119802018, 3119802018, 3119802018, 3119802018, 3119802018, 3119802018, 
3119802018, 3119802018, 3119802018, 3219882014, 3219882014, 3219882014, 
3219882014, 3219882014, 3219882014, 3219882014, 3219882014, 3219882014, 
3219882014, 3219882014, 3219882014, 3219882014, 3219882014, 3219882014, 
3219882014, 3219882014, 3219882014, 3219882015, 3219882015, 3219882015, 
3219882015, 3219882015, 3219882015, 3219882015, 3219882015, 3219882015, 
3219882015, 3219882015, 3219882015, 3219882015, 3219882015, 3219882015, 
3219882015, 3219882015, 3219882015, 3219912016, 3219912016, 3219912016, 
3219912016, 3219912016, 3219912016, 3219912016, 3219912016, 3219912016, 
3219912016, 3219912016, 3219912016, 3219912016, 3219912016, 3219912016, 
3219912016, 3219912016, 3219912016, 3219912017, 3219912017, 3219912017, 
3219912017, 3219912017, 3219912017, 3219912017), id_mdob = c(111990, 
111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 
111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 111990, 
111990, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 
221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 221995, 
221995, 221995, 221995, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 
311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 
311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 311980, 321988, 321988, 321988, 
321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 
321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 
321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 
321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 321988, 
321988, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 
321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 
321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 321991, 
321991, 321991), id = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32), survey_date = structure(c(17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 
17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 17532, 16102, 
16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 
16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 16467, 
16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 
16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16801, 
16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 
16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 16801, 17167, 
17167, 17167, 17167, 17167, 17167, 17167), class = "Date"), survey_year = c(2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017), mom_dob = c(1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 
1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 
1990, 1990, 1990, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 
1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 
1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 
1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1991, 1991, 
1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 
1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 
1991), date_year = c(2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 1998, 
1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006), mom_age = c(11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
22, 23, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 
35, 36, 37, 38, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14), birth_day = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), birth_month = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9), nchild1 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), nchild2 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), nchild3 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), nchild4 = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), nchild5 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), nchild6 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), nchild7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), nchild8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), nchild9 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), nchild10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), stock = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), hh_income_net = c(14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 
14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 14120, 
14120, 14120, 14120, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 
5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 5510, 
8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 
8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 
8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 
8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 
8203.990234375, 8203.990234375, 4850, 4850, 4850, 4850, 4850, 
4850, 4850, 4850, 4850, 4850, 4850, 4850, 4850, 4850, 4850, 4850, 
4850, 4850, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 
4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 4800, 2400, 2400, 
2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 
2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 2400, 3410, 3410, 3410, 3410, 3410, 3410, 
3410), marital_stat = c(20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), emp_stat = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3), disability_stat = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), weight = c(1294.89001464844, 
1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 
1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1294.89001464844, 1975.36999511719, 
1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 
1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 
1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 
1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 1975.36999511719, 
1975.36999511719, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 
1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1412, 1368, 
1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 
1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 1368, 989, 989, 989, 989, 989, 
989, 989, 989, 989, 989, 989, 989, 989, 989, 989, 989, 989, 989, 
1039, 1039, 1039, 1039, 1039, 1039, 1039), region = c(2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), birth_country = c(616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), birth_citizenship = c(616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), residence = c(616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 
616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 616, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), age_sq = c(784, 
784, 784, 784, 784, 784, 784, 784, 784, 784, 784, 784, 784, 784, 
784, 784, 784, 784, 529, 529, 529, 529, 529, 529, 529, 529, 529, 
529, 529, 529, 529, 529, 529, 529, 529, 529, 1444, 1444, 1444, 
1444, 1444, 1444, 1444, 1444, 1444, 1444, 1444, 1444, 1444, 1444, 
1444, 1444, 1444, 1444, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 
625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 676, 676, 676, 
676, 676, 676, 676, 676, 676, 676, 676, 676, 676, 676, 676, 676, 
676, 676, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 
576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 
625), educcat = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), educcat_college = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), maritalcat = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), hh_income_annual_usd = c(45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 
45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 
45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 45184, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 
17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 
17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 17632, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 
26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 
26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 
26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 26252.76875, 
26252.76875, 15520, 15520, 15520, 15520, 15520, 15520, 15520, 
15520, 15520, 15520, 15520, 15520, 15520, 15520, 15520, 15520, 
15520, 15520, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 
15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 15360, 
15360, 15360, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 
7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 7680, 10912, 
10912, 10912, 10912, 10912, 10912, 10912), hh_income_annual_log = c(10.7184983208529, 
10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 
10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 
10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 
10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 10.7184983208529, 
10.7184983208529, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 
9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 
9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 
9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 
9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 9.77747071195264, 10.175526738648, 
10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 
10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 
10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 
10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 10.175526738648, 
10.175526738648, 9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 
9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 
9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 
9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 
9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 9.64988479373721, 9.63952200670166, 
9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 
9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 
9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 
9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 9.63952200670166, 
9.63952200670166, 8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 
8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 
8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 
8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 
8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 8.94637482614172, 9.29761838008324, 
9.29761838008324, 9.29761838008324, 9.29761838008324, 9.29761838008324, 
9.29761838008324, 9.29761838008324), rural = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), newborn = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    family500 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), stock_sq = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -115L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please provide data that have the problem of interest. i.e. none of the sample mdob_id have more than 18 rows, and none of the child columns have any values

Comment: Sorry, I see that one of your sample `id_mdob` has 36 values, but there are no rows with any children. It would help to have some data. However, I've offered a solution that I think does the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do it for you, assuming your data frame is `hx`:

1. pivot the data of interest longer
2. grouping by both the id with the year and the id without, sum the number of births
3. sort in descending order of births and with the year (id_mdob_sy)
4. slice off the first row for each group; if ties, the prior step will kthe row with the maximum year
5. select just the full id, and use this in an inner_join back to the original dataset

```
hx %>% inner_join(
  hx %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("nchild")) %>% 
    select(id_mdob,id_mdob_sy,name,value) %>% 
    group_by(id_mdob,id_mdob_sy) %>% 
    summarize(births=sum(value,na.rm=T)) %>% 
    arrange(desc(births), desc(id_mdob_sy)) %>% 
    slice_head(n = 1) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(id_mdob_sy)
)
```

Output (Note the reduction from 115 to 79 rows, as 36 rows from the two duplicated ids have been dropped):

```
# A tibble: 79 × 40
   id_mdob_sy id_mdob    id survey_date survey_year mom_dob date_year mom_age birth_day birth_month nchild1 nchild2 nchild3 nchild4 nchild5 nchild6 nchild7 nchild8
        <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <date>            <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <lgl>   <lgl>  
 1 1119902018  111990    11 2018-01-01         2018    1990      2001      11        NA          NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA      NA     
 2 1119902018  111990    11 2018-01-01         2018    1990      2002      12        NA          NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA      NA     
 3 1119902018  111990    11 2018-01-01         2018    1990      2003      13        NA          NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA      NA     
 4 1119902018  111990    11 2018-01-01         2018    1990      2004      14        NA          NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA      NA     
 5 1119902018  111990    11 2018-01-01         2018    1990      2005      15        NA          NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA      NA     
 6 1119902018  111990    11 2018-01-01         2018    1990      2006      16        NA          NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA      NA     
 7 1119902018  111990    11 2018-01-01         2018    1990      2007      17        NA          NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA      NA     
 8 1119902018  111990    11 2018-01-01         2018    1990      2008      18        NA          NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA      NA     
 9 1119902018  111990    11 2018-01-01         2018    1990      2009      19        NA          NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA      NA     
10 1119902018  111990    11 2018-01-01         2018    1990      2010      20        NA          NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA NA      NA     
# … with 69 more rows, and 22 more variables: nchild9 <lgl>, nchild10 <lgl>, stock <dbl>, hh_income_net <dbl>, marital_stat <dbl>, emp_stat <dbl>,
#   disability_stat <dbl>, weight <dbl>, region <dbl>, birth_country <dbl>, birth_citizenship <dbl>, residence <dbl>, age_sq <dbl>, educcat <dbl>,
#   educcat_college <dbl>, maritalcat <dbl>, hh_income_annual_usd <dbl>, hh_income_annual_log <dbl>, rural <dbl>, newborn <dbl>, family500 <dbl>, stock_sq <dbl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I think this is the right approach, but when I run the above code, it seems the women with the children are being dropped. To reference the 2 examples in my original post, with this code:                                                  3219882014 and 3219882015 --> 3219882015 gets properly kept. For 3219912016 and 3219912017 --> 3219912017 was dropped instead of 3219912016. I've updated the dput in the post to include the first 250 rows.

Comment: *first 115 rows

Comment: hmm, see if my update fixed it. (I'm extending the call to `arrange()` and using `slice_head(n=1)` instead of `slice_max()`